# How to check a specific data exists in an array of data

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
$vehicleNo=strip_tags(trim(Input::get('vehcleNumber1'))) . '-' . strip_tags(trim(Input::get('vehcleNumber2')));
```

*its an vehicle no typed in textfield and i want to check this data already exist in $vehicles(array of data of vehicles no) or not*

```
$date = Carbon::today()->subDays(1);
$vehicles = Customer_details::select('vechicle_no')->where('branch_id',$branchId)
           ->where( 'entry_date', '>=', $date)
           ->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Please post the output of `$vehicles`. It is hard to imagine how your array will be.

Comment: result of $vehicleNo is = KL11H-4444

Comment: Why specifically as an array? It might be easier to return your query as a collection and use a collection method to check? Alternatively, don't fetch any collection and just check it with Eloquent? Have you tried checking the Laravel docs? You won't get any answers until you clear up whether you specifically want this as an array or not.

Comment: result of $vehicles is = Array ( [0] => Array ( [vechicle_no] => ds-3333 ) [1] => Array ( [vechicle_no] => KL11H-4444 ) )

Answer (score 1):

You can search by:

```
$is_exists = in_array($vehicleNo, array_column($vehicles, 'vechicle_no')); //will return true or false
if($is_exists) {
 //value exists in array
} else {
 //value not exists in array
}
```

Comment: @Abhijith18p the best way to thank is to accept answer if solution worked for you :)

Comment: The answer is very useful  and you made my day

Comment: @Abhijith18p Glad to hear that. Please upvote and accept it as the answer.